# vim: use string from search in replace command

Tags: regular-expression, vim

I often use vim `/` search command to verify my regular expressions (just to see what it matches). After that I usually use the `:%s` replace command, where I use that regexp from search as a string to be replaced, e.g. I first look for such string:

```
/TP-\(\d\{5\}\)-DD-\d\{3\}
```

It matches exactly what I want, so I do my replace:

```
:%s/TP-\(\d\{5\}\)-DD-\d\{3\}/\1/g
```

But I have to write again entire regexp here. Usually that regexp is much longer, that's why I'm looking for solution:

Is there any existing shortcut or vim script for pasting that search pattern directly into replace command?

I use vim in terminal (no gvim).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general, an empty regular expression means to use the previously entered regular expression, so `:%s//\1/g` should do what you want.

Comment: Woah, it's that easy! Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Also, if you want to verify or modify the last used pattern, you can use [Control-r](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R) then  `/` to insert the contents of the [search pattern register (`/`)](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%2f) directly into a partially typed command line (e.g. right after `:%s/`).

Comment: thats very useful hint as well. Thanks @Chris! +1

Comment: What if I want to follow up "\1" with a number like say 23? How do I avoid it being interpreted as "\123"?

Comment: @Champ As back references only go up to `\9`, there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Another good way to see past regexes searches as well as Ex commands and make changes to them is to edit these commands in normal mode. From this Mode you will have all your vim powers including copy and paste.

- Searching: rather than `?` or `/` for searching, try `q/` or `q?`
- for Ex Commands, rather than `:` try `q:`
- to exit this mode use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

To read more see [`:help q:`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q%3A).